# Javascript word-count for any given DOM element

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there's a way to count the words inside a div for example. Say we have a div like so:

```
<div id="content">
hello how are you?
</div>
```

Then have the JS function return an integer of 4.

Is this possible? I have done this with form elements but can't seem to do it for non-form ones.

Any ideas?

g

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you know that the DIV is *only* going to have text in it, you can [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```
var count = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML.split(' ').length;
```

If the div can have HTML tags in it, you're going to have to traverse its children looking for text nodes:

```
function get_text(el) {
    ret = "";
    var length = el.childNodes.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if(node.nodeType != 8) {
            ret += node.nodeType != 1 ? node.nodeValue : get_text(node);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
var words = get_text(document.getElementById('content'));
var count = words.split(' ').length;
```

This is the same logic that the jQuery library uses to achieve the effect of its [`text()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) function. jQuery is a pretty awesome library that in this case is not necessary. However, if you find yourself doing a lot of DOM manipulation or AJAX then you might want to check it out.

**EDIT**:

As noted by Gumbo in the comments, the way we are splitting the strings above would count two consecutive spaces as a word. If you expect that sort of thing (and even if you don't) it's probably best to avoid it by splitting on a regular expression instead of on a simple space character. Keeping that in mind, instead of doing the above split, you should do something like this:

```
var count = words.split(/\s+/).length;
```

The only difference being on what we're passing to the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function.

Comment: You'll have to get the text node first.

Comment: This will count tags as words though, which is why I would prefer the text() version provided by jQuery.

Comment: I know, I was working as soon as I posted it to port text over to plain javascript to provide that as an alternative. Not everyone needs jQuery in their lives. :)

Comment: +1, I do like that you took the logic for text from the jQuery library :)

Comment: You should cache el.childNodes.length in a local variable - currently you're querying it on every iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure how much HTML you'd really need to make that matter. :) A heck of a lot, I'd say. But, I guess, I must acquiesce your request.

Comment: You should better use a regular expression to take multiple whitespace characters into account.

Comment: Would `.textContent` (or `.innerText` for IE) not be sufficient instead of the descending traversal?

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino: bug fix for your code, u better use: var count = (words.length ? words.split(/\s+/).length : 0) cause split returns an array with one empty string if words is an empty string, so you would get one word count.

Answer (score 7):

Paolo Bergantino's second solution is incorrect for empty strings or strings that begin or end with whitespaces. Here's the fix:

```
var count = !s ? 0 : (s.split(/^\s+$/).length === 2 ? 0 : 2 +
    s.split(/\s+/).length - s.split(/^\s+/).length - s.split(/\s+$/).length);
```

**Explanation:** If the string is empty, there are zero words; If the string has only whitespaces, there are zero words; Else, count the number of whitespace groups without the ones from the beginning and the end of the string.

Answer (score 6):

```
string_var.match(/[^\s]+/g).length
```

seems like it's a better method than

```
string_var.split(/\s+/).length
```

At least it won't count "word " as 2 words -- ['word'] rather than ['word', '']. And it doesn't really require any funny add-on logic.

Comment: Better but it stil counts empty string '' as 1. Try:  `string_var.match(/[^\s]+/g).length - 1;`

Answer (score 5):

Or just use [Countable.js](http://radlikewhoa.github.io/Countable/) to do the hard job ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.deepText= function(hoo){
    var A= [];
    if(hoo){
        hoo= hoo.firstChild;
        while(hoo!= null){
            if(hoo.nodeType== 3){
                A[A.length]= hoo.data;
            }
            else A= A.concat(arguments.callee(hoo));
            hoo= hoo.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

I'd be fairly strict about what a word is-

```
function countwords(hoo){
    var text= document.deepText(hoo).join(' ');
    return text.match(/[A-Za-z\'\-]+/g).length;
}
alert(countwords(document.body))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this:

```
function CountWords (this_field, show_word_count, show_char_count) {
    if (show_word_count == null) {
        show_word_count = true;
    }
    if (show_char_count == null) {
        show_char_count = false;
    }
    var char_count = this_field.value.length;
    var fullStr = this_field.value + " ";
    var initial_whitespace_rExp = /^[^A-Za-z0-9]+/gi;
    var left_trimmedStr = fullStr.replace(initial_whitespace_rExp, "");
    var non_alphanumerics_rExp = rExp = /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/gi;
    var cleanedStr = left_trimmedStr.replace(non_alphanumerics_rExp, " ");
    var splitString = cleanedStr.split(" ");
    var word_count = splitString.length -1;
    if (fullStr.length <2) {
        word_count = 0;
    }
    if (word_count == 1) {
        wordOrWords = " word";
    } else {
        wordOrWords = " words";
    }
    if (char_count == 1) {
        charOrChars = " character";
    } else {
        charOrChars = " characters";
    }
    if (show_word_count & show_char_count) {
        alert ("Word Count:\n" + "    " + word_count + wordOrWords + "\n" + "    " + char_count + charOrChars);
    } else {
        if (show_word_count) {
            alert ("Word Count:  " + word_count + wordOrWords);
        } else {
            if (show_char_count) {
                alert ("Character Count:  " + char_count + charOrChars);
            }
        }
    }
    return word_count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The get_text function in Paolo Bergantino's answer didn't work properly for me when two child nodes have no space between them. eg <h1>heading</h1><p>paragraph</p> would be returned as headingparagraph (notice lack of space between the words). So prepending a space to the nodeValue fixes this. But it introduces a space at the front of the text but I found a word count function that trims it off (plus it uses several regexps to ensure it counts words only). Word count and edited get_text functions below:

```
function get_text(el) {
    ret = "";
    var length = el.childNodes.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if(node.nodeType != 8) {
            ret += node.nodeType != 1 ? ' '+node.nodeValue : get_text(node);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

function wordCount(fullStr) {
    if (fullStr.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        fullStr = fullStr.replace(/\r+/g, " ");
        fullStr = fullStr.replace(/\n+/g, " ");
        fullStr = fullStr.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+/gi, "");
        fullStr = fullStr.replace(/^\s+/, "");
        fullStr = fullStr.replace(/\s+$/, "");
        fullStr = fullStr.replace(/\s+/gi, " ");
        var splitString = fullStr.split(" ");
        return splitString.length;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

kennebec's word counter is really good. But the one I've found includes a number as a word which is what I needed. Still, that's easy to add to kennebec's. But kennebec's text retrieval function will have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should account for preceding & trailing whitespaces

```
const wordCount = document.querySelector('#content').innerText.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
```

Comment: +1 for `innerText`. The `innerText` property provides built-in functionality to get text from an HTML element, while the other answers provide custom solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`string_var.match(/[^\s]+/g).length - 1;`