# character limit jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello 
Im looking for a function that will allow me limit number of characters in li tag.

Tried to do it that way:

```
$('li.latestnewsfooterCol').limit('5');
```

but this dont seem to work.

Can anyone help me please?

thank you in advance.

Comment: why do u wanna do this ?

Comment: How do you reset the word limit back to the original state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Part 1: Limiting number of characters

This will go through each selected `li` and reduce the contents to 5 character using the **[`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** method.

Slice extracts up to, but not including the end slice.

```
$('li.latestnewsfooterCol').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text( $this.text().slice(0,5) );
});
```

### [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9xwA/)

To make it into a function:

```
var maxNum = function($elie, num) {
    var $this;
    $elie.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.text( $this.text().slice(0,num) );
    });
}
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9FEZ/)**

Call the above with a jQuery object like, `limit($('li.latestnewsfooterCol'), 5);`

I use `.each()` in both cases in case you have more than one element selected.

---

### Part 2: Limiting words

Word count are a little more complicated. **[Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765419/javascript-word-count-for-any-given-dom-element)**. Fortunately it's much compacter on jQuery:

```
var maxNum = function($elie, num) {
    var $this;
    $elie.each(function() {
        $this = $(this); 
        $this.text( $this.text().split(/\s+/).slice(0,num).join(" ") );
    });
}

$(function() {
    maxNum($('li.latestnewsfooterCol'),5);
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rsDsx/)**

First the text is split into an array by whitespace,`$this.text().split(/\t+/)`. Then the array is sliced to the right length and rejoined with spaces, `.slice(0,num).join(" ")` Note that this might replace tabs or line breaks with spaces.

---

As a note, consider that this will be only available to users with Javascript enabled.

---

Comment: This is great! But is there a way that I can count words in similar way? Sorry for messing up

Comment: @Dom - Edited in word count. Arrays also have a `.slice()` method.

Comment: Great answer, much less code then previous ways i've used before.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please be more specific? Do you want to have something like

```
...
<li>A very long list item</li>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function limit(no_of_chars) {

    }
    limit(5);
</script>
```

to output

```
A ver
```

?

Comment: Yes. I have links in my footer that simply dont fit. Just want to limit them to number of characters for that particular tag

Comment: @Dom, you should probably do something like that server-side. Do you want your design to break if users have Javascript disabled, or use either an old browser or a newly-released browser that your jQuery script doesn't support? Edit: also, 5 characters is... pretty small.

Comment: The problem is that I am using it for joomla. If i would wanted to do it on server site would affect entire module on whole site. it is a latest news feed that shows on footer and LHS. Only on footer i need to limit numb of characters. I know that it might break for older browsers. although it will not affect look and feel too bad, so I can cope with it. Thank you for your advice.