# Estimation time to read an article In ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How can I estimate time to read an article  like docs.asp.net website

[docs.asp.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

At the top of all articles, it says you need xxx minutes to read. I think they are using an algorithm to estimate time

How can I do that!

Thanks in advance

Comment: No research effort, no attempt made.

Answer (score 3):

The words read per minute average is about **250-300**, once you know this you just need to:

- Get the article word count.
- Divide this number by 275 (more or less).
- Round the result to get a integer number of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a study conducted in 2012](http://iovs.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2166061), the average reading speed of an adult for text in English is: 228±30 words, 313±38 syllables, and  987±118 characters per minute.

You can therefore calculate an average time to read a particular article by counting one of these factors and dividing by that average speed. Syllables per minute is probably the most accurate, but for computers, words and characters are easier to count.

Study Citation:
*Standardized Assessment of Reading Performance: The New International Reading Speed Texts IReST by
Susanne Trauzettel-Klosinski; Klaus Dietz; the IReST Study Group, published in Investigative Ophthalmology & Visual Science August 2012, Vol.53, 5452-5461*

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution here, on how
to get an estimated read time of any article or blog post  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63820743/12490386

here's an easy one

1. Divide your total word count by 200.
2. You’ll get a decimal number, in this case, 4.69. The first part of your decimal number is your minute. In this case, it’s 4.
3. Take the second part — the decimal points — and multiply that by 0.60. Those are your seconds. Round up or down as necessary to get a whole second. In this case, 0.69 x 0.60 = 0.414. We’ll round that to 41 seconds.
4. The result? 938 words = a 4 minute, 41 second read.